# How can I format a string to remove certain characters (.NET Razor)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

go easy on me - I'm new to .NET... I need to know how to take a string like "/About-Us" and make it into "About Us". I have found questions on here that I think may answer this, but I don't understand which part of the answer I need to apply to my situation.

I am trying to do the following:

```
@{
    var CurrentPage = Request.Path;
    CurrentPage.Replace("-", " ");
    CurrentPage.Replace("/", "");
}

@CurrentPage
```

Since the output of Request.Path is "/About-Us", I thought the .Replace would make the "-" into a space, and remove the "/". What is the best way to accomplish this conversion?

Comment: I'd suggest not tying your page titles to the url routes.

Comment: This code is being used to mark menu items as active :)

Comment: That is good advice though... I may or may not be using this method. I'm just toying around with .NET.

Comment: I'd suggest setting the title per controller, perhaps in the ctor, or using a route/title map structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to assign it back to the variable:

```
var CurrentPage =  "/About-Us";
CurrentPage = CurrentPage.Replace("-", " ");
CurrentPage = CurrentPage.Replace("/", "");
Console.WriteLine (CurrentPage);
```

Or chained:

```
CurrentPage = CurrentPage.Replace("-", " ").Replace("/", "");
```

Both output:

> About Us

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a **new** string in which all occurrences of a specified string in the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

Comment: I ran with the CurrentPage = CurrentPage.Replace("-", " ").Replace("/", "");

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that strings in .NET are immutable objects, that is to say, their values cannot be changed.  Instead, when you perform an action manipulating the value of the string, it will return a new string instead.  If you look at the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) method, it has a return type of string.

The solution is to assign the result of calling `Replace`.

```
@{
    var CurrentPage = Request.Path;
    CurrentPage = CurrentPage.Replace("-", " ");
    CurrentPage = CurrentPage.Replace("/", "");
}
@CurrentPage
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Immutability) for more details about string immutability.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I was trying to type in the first place. I'm rusty...